# JAVAFX:Create stage and text area at runtime

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am new to `JavaFX`, here I want to create a new `Stage` and one `TextArea` inside it at the run-time and I want to pass a line to that text area and update it continuously.

Can anybody please give me the example of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("TEST");
link.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                TextArea text = new TextArea():

                VBox vbox = new VBox();
                Button close = new Button();
                close.setText("Close");
                close.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        stage.close();
                    }
                });
                vbox.getChildren().addAll(text, close);
                Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.setMinWidth(100);
                stage.setMinHeight(100);
                stage.show();
                // ...
                text.setText("update");
    }
});
```

Comment: WIll explain my requirement in more details.There is one link in my text area if i click on that link i want to open new window and one text area should be present in that window so that afterwards i can update that text area.So, how i will create the new stage after click on window?

Comment: After inserting above code i am getting below error.no suitable constructor found for VBox(TextArea)
    constructor VBox.VBox(double) is not applicable
      (actual argument TextArea cannot be converted to double by method invocation conversion)
    constructor VBox.VBox() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)...I also want to add two buttons one for hiding window and other for closing window

Comment: Maybe there was a version difference. I updated the code again, this time it should work in any case.

Comment: Adam, 
Thanks for your quick reply 
I will try to explain you  my requirement in bit more detail.
I have n thread/process and want to display the updated of each thread in different stage and respective text area. so want to have resp. n Stages and respective n text ares. so was thinking of creating stage array list and wanted to update its text area. How do I do access the text area if a specific stage ?

Comment: You would need to store the reference to that text area beneath the reference to the stage. Or you could iterate through the children of the stage root with `stage.getScene().getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable()`